# PowerBI - Week Number on X-Axis

Tags: powerbi, dax, week-number

I have a line graph in PowerBI and in my date dimension I have the Week Number for every date (note that this is a custom week number with the week starting on Friday).

Whenever I put it on a the x-axis, PowerBI groups all the weeks together, regarless of year... so Week 1 of year 2015 will be grouped together with Week 1 of 2016...

I think to myself: "Ok, no problem, I'll just add the Year after every week number so I'll have 1-2016, 2-2016, and so on."

Well PowerBI sees this concatenation as a string value so when I put that on the graph, it goes

1-2016, 1-2017, 2-2016, 2-2017, 3-2016, 4-2016, and so on....

I've tried sorting the new column by the old week number column, but it does the same thing. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. I recommend a separate (hidden) sort column that sorts alphabetically (i.e. year first, then 2 digit week). In other words, 1-2016 = 201601.

This way, all the weeks for 2016 sort before the weeks for 2017, and the weeks sort in the right order too. (A 1 digit week would mean 20161 will be followed by 201610, which you don't want either.)